# How to start a fail-safe graphics session? (with mouse & web browser)

Tags: grub2, nvidia, graphics, recovery-mode

How do I boot into a "Recovery mode" "fail-safeX"  graphical session to troubleshoot graphics drivers with a desktop & mouse?

That way I can use a web browser & nice GUI tools to fix regular video drivers. (Nvidia, AMD, Intel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Start your computer,
  Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, or has almost finished.
  (During this time you will probably see a logo of your computer manufacturer.)

Quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (or <kbd>Escape</kbd> key on some computers), which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu.
  (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.)

[image: Grub menu]

2. Use the <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to navigate/highlight the entry with `Recovery mode` or `advanced options`  (usually the second one)  press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue booting into the Recovery Menu.
3. from the recovery menu Select **Resume normal boot** & hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.
   [image: recovery menu]
   [recovery mode wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

   now your'll be using the fail safe graphics drivers in a recovery session

use can use a Web browser & go to askubuntu.com for help fixing drivers !

Comment: This saved 3 hrs of my time.  "failsafeX  Run in failsafe graphics mode" no longer comes up on my GRUB, Lubuntu 20.  "Resume Normal Boot" looked like a total lose with the NVidia Display Driver wiped out--I thought it would just reboot into a black screen again, huhn.  The correct answer is unintuitive.  Thank you much.