# My laptop is not booting after running "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

My laptop has 4GB Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650.
I am using dual boot (Ubuntu 21.04 + Windows 10).
Today I used a command -

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After it I reboot my laptop and choose for boot with Ubuntu from Grub menu. But my laptop is not booting with Ubuntu now. Continues with black screen and a white blinking cursor at the top left corner.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this:

**Can you get to a plain terminal shell?** Try hitting Ctrl Alt 3 and logging in that way. if that works, [do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) after getting a terminal shell.

**Can you [boot into safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901326/how-to-start-a-fail-safe-graphics-session-with-mouse-web-browser)?** if so, go into safe/recovery mode and try this [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Answer (score 0):

There a few things you could try. Diable Windows 10 fast start: [https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045548][1]

Reboot into Ubuntu. If you still get the ominous blinking cursor, hit CTRL+ALT+F3, and log in from there. Type `sudo apt-get -f install` Look at the errors, if any.

If you can't get to a terminal, reboot into Ubuntu and hit 'e' really quick. That will bring up the boot layout of GRUB. At the end of the kernel line put `/bin/bash` or `init 1` Then hit CTRL+x.

Enter the root password, if you made one. Otherwise, I'm not sure how Ubuntu handles login from `init 1` But once you're in, `sudo apt-get -f install` again.

If none of that works, but you can get to a terminal, or log into init level one `init 1` try `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-driver` then reboot or `gdm3`